How to implement WhatsApp Flows with Twilio
Meta has a feature - "WhatsApp Flows"|: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/flows
I'm using Twilio for WhatsApp, and looking for an efficient way to work with this feature on Twilio.
NOTE: this isn't the Flows that they have in Twilio Studio, but a WhatsApp native feature called "WhatsApp Flows"
Twilio don't mention anywhere in their documentation on how to use WhatsApp Flows with Twilio

As of now, Twilio is not yet supporting this feature.
However, you can use this form to request access to the pilot once available :).
